# Is it possible to use LSTM predictions as inputs for next time steps?

Tags: python, pytorch, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am working with LSTM (in PyTorch) for multivariate time series prediction. Let’s imagine the situation: I have 2 time series, A and B, and I want to predict t-value of B using previous values of A and B (before t). Such prediction works fine, my model gets good results.

But what if (during testing, after training) I want to use predicted values of B as inputs for next time step instead of real values? For example: I predict first value of B, make a step, put predicted value instead of a real, and make prediction again. Then I use two predicted values instead of real two, and so on. In some steps only predicted values will be in time series B.

Are there any possibilities to do that?

Comment: Teacher Forcing converges faster. In the testing mode, you can use beam search for optimal performance

Comment: During training I use teacher forcing approach. Problems occur during testing when predicted values as inputs for next time steps. E.g. [x1, x2, x3] to predict x4, at next time step I will use [x2, x3, x4] to predict x5, and so on, values after x3 are prediction, not from test data but my lstm does not converge.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what people do for machine translation and text generation in general. In this case, the LSTM predicts a distribution over a vocabulary, you select one word and use it as an input to the network in the next step. See [PyTotrch tutorial on machine translation](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/seq2seq_translation_tutorial.html) for more details.

The important point is that the LSTM executed in two regimes:

- For training: as a standard sequence labeling. It is provided input and it should predict one step in the future.
- For inference: It gradually generates new samples and uses them as the next input. In PyTorch, this needs to be implemented with an explicit for loop.

Comment: Thanks for answer! It really improved my understanding. But the problem lies in a bit different direction. It turned out that I do exactly what you recommended. The problem is that when I use prediction for inputs, e.g. [x1, x2, x3] to predict x4, at next time step I will use [x2, x3, x4] to predict x5, and so on, values after x3 are prediction, not from test data, my lstm does not converge, but when I use only test data everything is fine. I checked the types of inputs and they are the same for both cases.